# C# Month and Day Occurrence in between the dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I've a Month and day list and i need to search each month and day in this list in between the given dates. Can any one suggest me to do best way to get desired output.

Eg:

> Month day list -> 01/11, 03/15, 05/25, 09/01
>
> Between dates -> 01/01/2012 to 07/01/13

Expected result:

> 01/11/2012, 01/11/2013
>
> 03/15/2012, 03/15/2013
>
> 05/25/2012, 05/25/2013
>
> 09/01/2012

I tried like this but it gives memory exception and time and memory complexity increases if from date and to date having number of years gap, is there any quick solution to get it?

```
DateTime[] dateDates = new DateTime[dateTypeList.Rows.Count];
//convert strings to datetimes:
for (int i = 0; i < dateTypeList.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dateDates[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(string.Format("{0}/{1}", Convert.ToInt32(dateTypeList.Rows[i]["Month"]), Convert.ToInt32(dateTypeList.Rows[i]["Day"]))));
}

//define start and end time:
DateTime dateStart = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
DateTime dateEnd = new DateTime(2013, 7, 1);

List<DateTime> results = new List<DateTime>();
//loop days between start and end time:
for (DateTime a = dateStart; a <= dateEnd; a.AddDays(1))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dateDates.Length; i++)
    {
        if (dateDates[i] == a)
        {
            results.Add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us some code for your list

Comment: @Habib month and day is exist in data table columns by month and day columns.

Comment: @user1805169: If you've only got the month and day, how can you *possibly* check for dates between 2012-1-1 and 2013-7-1? What value would you want to exclude?

Comment: @JonSkeet If you check expected result years and from date to date years you'll get exactly what i want.

Comment: @user1805169: Ah, now I see what you're after. Okay, will edit.

Comment: @user1805169: See my answer now. Hopefully it does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, now I see more about what you're trying to achieve.

So you have input of:

- Start date and end date
- A list of month/day pairs. Currently you don't *actually* have this, but that's what you've logically got.

Your current code doesn't take account of the fact that there can be multiple years at all.

First, let's transform your data table appropriately:

```
var monthDays = dateTypeList.Rows.AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(row => new { Month = row.Field<int>("Month")
                                                 Day = row.Field<int>("Day") })
                            .ToList();
```

Now you can use:

```
for (int year = startDate.Year; year <= endDate.Year; year++)
{
    foreach (var pair in monthDays)
    {
        // Avoid creating a date which doesn't exist...
        if (!DateTime.IsLeapYear(year) && pair.Month == 2 && pair.Day == 29)
        {
            continue;
        }
        DateTime date = new DateTime(year, pair.Month, pair.Day);
        if (date <= startDate && date <= endDate)
        {
            results.Add(date);
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is the immediate problem:

```
for (DateTime a = dateStart; a <= dateEnd; a.AddDays(1))
```

DateTime is immutable, so `AddDays` has no effect if you don't use the return value. You want:

```
for (DateTime a = dateStart; a <= dateEnd; a = a.AddDays(1))
```

I'd also change this code:

```
dateDates[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(
  Convert.ToDateTime(string.Format("{0}/{1}", 
      Convert.ToInt32(dateTypeList.Rows[i]["Month"]), 
      Convert.ToInt32(dateTypeList.Rows[i]["Day"]))));
```

- It's going via a string representation for no reason
- It's calling `Convert.ToDateTime` twice for no reason
- It's *assuming* that the system date format is month/day, which is culture-specific

Comment: Is there any way to optimize above code instead of for and foreach?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dayList = new List<customMonthDay>{
            new customMonthDay{ Day = 11, Month = 1 },
            new customMonthDay{ Day = 15, Month = 3 },
            new customMonthDay{ Day = 25, Month = 5 },
            new customMonthDay{ Day = 1, Month = 9 }
        };

        var startDate = new DateTime( 2012, 1, 1 );
        var endDate = new DateTime( 2013, 7, 1 );

        var listYears = getYears(startDate, endDate);

        var includedDays = new List<customMonthDayYear>();

        foreach (var year in listYears)
        {
            foreach (var day in dayList)
            {
                var candidateday = new customMonthDayYear { Year = year, Month = day.Month, Day = day.Day };
                if (candidateday.ToDateTime() > startDate && candidateday.ToDateTime() < endDate)
                    includedDays.Add(candidateday);
            }
        }

        includedDays.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ToDateTime().ToString()));
    }

    protected static List<int> getYears(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        var years = new List<int>();
        int diff = end.Year - start.Year;
        for ( int i = 0; i <= diff; i++ )
        {
            years.Add( start.Year + i );
        }
        return years;
    }

    public class customMonthDay
    {
        public int Day { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
    }

    public class customMonthDayYear : customMonthDay
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }

        public DateTime ToDateTime()
        {
            return new DateTime(Year, Month, Day);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's just a quick sample with hardcoded data. Just to point out how to avoid the culture nightmare :) I am also not checking in getYears if start is < than end, and I should.

Answer (score 0):

use following :

```
for each date in list

 a.Equals(date) or a.CompareTo(date)
```

Comment: There will then be a huge chance that no dates will ever be included in the results.

Comment: Well it's definitely the way to go. Way smarter to check the inserted dates rather than all dates between start and end time. Sry didn't realise until after that @rikitikitik commented the previous code, which I agree on did look a bit off :D

Comment: foreach (DateTime d in dateDates){ if(d>=startdate && d<=enddate){ result.add(d);}} Something like this

Comment: @WozzeC: yes. Please checkout DateTime class methods .Equals and .CompareTo() .  ----for this question .CompareTo() is enough as its return value indicates whether current datetime object is earlier, equals or greater than datetime obj in CompareTo(date).

Comment: @rohank I agree, .Equals and CompareTo are way better to use than >= and <=. But I always forget what the results are from those, which is why I didn't use those. :)

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me, but is there any way still we can reduce this one by using linq or something?**

```
private List<DateTime> GetDates(DataTable dateTypeList, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
        {
            List<DateTime> results = new List<DateTime>();
            fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate.ToShortDateString());
            toDate=Convert.ToDateTime(toDate.ToShortDateString());

            int minDay = fromDate.Day;
            int minMonth = fromDate.Month;
            int minYear = fromDate.Year;
            int maxDay = toDate.Day;
            int maxMonth = toDate.Month;
            int maxYear = toDate.Year;
            for (int j = minYear; j <= maxYear; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dateTypeList.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    int _day = Convert.ToInt32(dateTypeList.Rows[i]["Day"]);
                    int _month = Convert.ToInt32(dateTypeList.Rows[i]["Month"]);
                    DateTime tempDate = new DateTime(j, _month, _day);
                    if ((tempDate >= fromDate) && (tempDate <= toDate))
                    {
                        results.Add(tempDate);
                    }

                }
            }

            return dateTypeList;
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```